# Python detect USB drive then assign drive letter?

Tags: python, windows

Here is the problem. We have 100s of external 500gb USB drives. Each drive will travel to a new location through the year. What is the best way to automatically detect that a USB drive has been plugged into a Windows system, then assign a Z:\ drive letter? These USB drives will be plugged into lots of different computers so a script like this

```
import subprocess

diskpart_data = "z-drive.txt"
open (diskpart_data, "w").write ("""
select volume F: 
assign letter=Z
""")
subprocess.call ('diskpart /s %s' % diskpart_data)
```

is hard to use due to the dynamic nature of the mobile USB drive on different Windows systems all the time? Could you autodetect through WMI or do some kind of volume mount with NTFS?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if the Z: drive is already in use on the machine that it is being plugged into?

Comment: do the script need to be on the drive or on every windows machine it is plugged to ?

Comment: @Jim B
We choose the Z:\ drive because it's not used in the current environment where this will be implemented. The client will also know ahead of time that upon running this script not to have a z:\ drive mapped.

@slurdge
We get a USB drive, run a different python script that moves 6,000 videos to a videos directory. Then we use an access module to create hyperlinks in a report, referring to these videos. So mapping z:\videos\<filename> can be used across the board and wont break the links in the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as terabytest said, you may run a script from an autorun.inf in the root of the drive. personally, i would do with a batch script:

```
(echo select volume %~d0 && echo assign letter=Z) | diskpart
```

the `%~d0` retrieves the drive letter of the currently executing batch file.

if this is not sufficient, there is a way of being informed when a removable drive is inserted by using the [device management functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363224%28VS.85%29.aspx) of the Windows API. you have to first register for notification using [`RegisterDeviceNotification()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363431%28VS.85%29.aspx) then process the [`WM_DEVICECHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480%28VS.85%29.aspx) message in the event loop. unfortunately, this needs an event loop, and i don't know how you can easily create one in python (apart from creating it from scratch: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644928%28VS.85%29.aspx) is an example message loop, note that in your case you should not need to create a window, only have a message loop).

Answer (score 1):

You could try compiling that script to an exe and make an autorun file in the USB key which runs the script. Then the script does its things.
For the assigning the Z:\ letter thing, I'd suggest using Win32Com (even though I don't know if it can handle this) or use ctypes which will give you control on the windows dlls.