# How to get a file on a memory stick read into a python script?

Tags: python, path, directory, usb-flash-drive

I have a file on a memory stick which i want to use in my python script. The easiest way to do this would be to move the file into the directory it currently looks in but for security reasons i cant do this. How do i write the file location so that it successfully finds the file on the memory stick and reads it in? this is what ive tried...

```
import asciitable
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

x=asciitable.read('E:/ECBGF/bg0809_protected.txt', guess=False,delimiter='\t',fill_values=[('', '-999')])
```

Comment: if you use linux, you can just do a symbolic link to the directory of your choice.

Comment: im using windows but the python program im using runs through a linux server. How would i do the symbolic link?

Comment: have a look at "man ln"

Comment: In Linux you can read from memory stick as from regular disk. For example ubuntu automount your usb storages to /media directory with it's id.

Comment: What's wrong with `open('/path/to/file')`?

Comment: On Windows "memory sticks" are usually assigned a unique drive letter when inserted. If you know the drive letter (or can determine it), you should be able to read the file with regular Python file I/O calls. i.e. `with open('<drive>:\<filename.ext> as fin:`. A simple way to determine what the drive letter is would be to iterate through all the drive letters starting with `C` until you find the file.

Comment: A more sophisticated approach to determining the drive letter of a newly inserted flash drive would be to use the win32 API and watch for [`WM_DEVICECHANGE`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420131/detect-insertion-of-media-into-a-drive-using-windows-messages) messages. See also [Python detect USB drive then assign drive letter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771200/python-detect-usb-drive-then-assign-drive-letter/1775387#1775387).

Comment: i cant use open because i'm trying to read in the file within this    x=asciitable.read('', guess=False,delimiter='\t',fill_values=[('', '-999')]) where the file destination lies inbetween the ''   @martineau

Comment: Regardless of how you're reading the file, it has to have been opened somehow. If you'd show us some of your code, maybe the help you're getting would be better.

Comment: ive added the relevant section of code @martineau

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't explicitly open the file yourself, the simplest thing to do in this case would be to just make sure that the path to the file you pass `asciitable.read()` is valid. Here's what I mean:

```
import asciitable
import os
from string import ascii_uppercase
import sys

PATH_TEMPLATE = '{}:/ECBGF/bg0809_protected.txt'
for drive in ascii_uppercase[:-24:-1]: # letters 'Z' down to 'D'
    file_path = PATH_TEMPLATE.format(drive)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        break
else:
    print 'error, file not found'
    sys.exit(1)

x = asciitable.read(file_path, guess=False, delimiter='\t',
                    fill_values=[('', '-999')])
```